# How can I change the name of an input element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I know I can target an input element with a specific name, for example

```
$("textarea[name=form_textarea]").val();
```

However I can't seem to find any examples of how I could go about changing the name itself, is this possible?

Comment: check `prop()` or `attr()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("textarea[name=form_textarea]").attr("name", "new_name");

$("textarea").val("Name is: " + $("textarea").attr("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="form_textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: @corning: I'd use `prop` for it, but I don't think it really makes a difference with the `name` property / attribute, it's a directly reflected one.